# delay + distinctUntilChanged in RXjava with RXBindings

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I'm trying to monitor text changes with some delay to avoid spam from listener. But of course I don't want to receive some items that are already handled.

This observer

```
RxTextView.textChanges(editText)
                .delay(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .distinctUntilChanged()
                .filter(charSequence -> charSequence.length() != 0)
                .subscribe(charSequence1 -> Log.e("!@#", charSequence1));
```

emmits such an items when I enter "abcd":

```
E/!@#: abcd
E/!@#: abcd
E/!@#: abcd
E/!@#: abcd
```

So I receive the emmited items 4 times but the strings are equals and there is `distinctUntilChanged`. Why `distinctUntilChanged` not works in this case? Is it possible to achieve this logic with delay with rx operators?

Comment: If I remember correctly, textChanges or the text control reuses the same CharSequence so you get this kind of anomaly. You have to use `map(v -> new String(v))` before the delay to create an immutable copy.

Comment: Yes, it uses the same charsequence because I got the same chars each time. Maybe it works not as I expected, each time the emit is scheduled the result is really new (a, ab etc) and scheduled as a new one. And after 2 sec it returns the same char sequence 4 times. Seems like an expected behaviour. New string should Return a, ab, abc... Is it possible to return only last result when user stop typing? In this case abcd for one time? last() not for this issue as I understand. You can post your suggestion as an answer.

Comment: Look for examples of the `debounce` operator.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I remember correctly, textChanges or the text control reuses the same CharSequence so you get this kind of anomaly. You have to use map(v -> new String(v)) before the delay to create an immutable copy.

> Is it possible to return only last result when user stop typing? In this case abcd for one time? last() not for this issue as I understand.

Look for examples of the `debounce` operator.